# WPF DatePicker Control Display Dates

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I'm using WPF with MVVM implementation, and have a WPF DatePicker control. I've set the default date on my property using DateTime.Now, but I would like to disable all the Dates on the DatePicker control that fall before the current date so that the User cannot select any earlier dates.

I've tried setting this in xaml using FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now} in my SelectedDate property, and {x:Static sys:DateTime.Now} in most of the other properties (from another source) but the dates before the current dates are still displayed and still selectable.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're looking BlackoutDates property?

Here is more info of using the DatePicker control (including BlackoutDates):

[WPF Toolkit: Calendar & DatePicker Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-calendar-datepicker-walkthrough.aspx#blackout)

For example if you want to set your blackout dates from 1/1/2000 to present day you can do:

```
<Calendar.BlackoutDates>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/2000" End="{x:Static System:DateTime.Today}" />
</Calendar.BlackoutDates>
```

Where System namespace is defined as

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: This definitely seems like what I'm looking for...I would like to know though, (if you know), if there is a way to set the End property of the CalendarDateRange to automatically end at the Current day...So for example, that Start property starts at 01/01/0001 and should end at whatever the current date is...Is this at all possible? I've tried doing it using the x:Static sys:DateTime.Now but that seems to break my xaml completely

Comment: I tried using that as well but if I do I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException that says 'SelectedDate value is not valid.
Parameter name: d' .. Could this be because I used a DatePicker and then within the DatePicker I add <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>?

Comment: I believe your problem is that you're trying to set SelectedDate to one of the BlackoutedDates.

Comment: <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=CurrentModel.startDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              FirstDayOfWeek="Monday">
        <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
          <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/2000"
                             End="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Today}" />
       </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
  </DatePicker>

Comment: And to what date is CurrentModel.startDate?

Comment: CurrentModel is my ViewModel, which contains the Class instantion where startDate is declared

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DisplayDateStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [DisplayDateEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) properties to select what dates should be displayed in the control or if you want something more complex you can use [BlackOutDates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to select exactly what dates you don't want to be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

CalendarDateRange cdr = new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Today);
myCalendar.BlackoutDates.Add(cdr);

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
MyDatePicker.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendarblackoutdatescollection.adddatesinpast(v=vs.110).aspx